# livedemo.c Error: Failed to initialize PocketSphinx

Tags: gstreamer, pocketsphinx

The pocketsphinx installation from github contains one file called livedemo.c for gstreamer plugin testing which I finally managed to compile using

```
gcc livedemo.c -o livedemo.out $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0)
```

but when I try to start it using

```
./livedemo.out anyfile.raw
```

I get an output, the last few lines:

```
Running...
Error: Failed to initialize PocketSphinx
Returned, stopping playback
Deleting pipeline
```

I am wondering what the problem is, because this is code from the pocketsphinx installation. By the way, livedemo.py is working. What am I doing wrong? Maybe the audio file was misformatted (but I tried many different), could you provide me an audio file that is working for you so I can check?

When I correct the filenames, I get the following output in gdb:

```
Thread 2 "file-source:src" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x73eb2470 (LWP 1310)]
0x768b4878 in ps_get_hyp (ps=0x19cd50, out_best_score=0x73eb1bf0, 
    out_best_score@entry=0x73eb1be8) at pocketsphinx.c:1231
1231        hyp = ps_search_hyp(ps->search, out_best_score);
```

Comment: It fails to find the model files. You can see that in the log above.

Comment: Thank you. How can I include the model files properly?

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev please tell me how to properly include the model files in c. I cannot find a single tutorial on the web how to do this...

Comment: Edit the file paths in the sources and recompile.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I changed test.lmctl to /home/pi/pocketsphinx/test/data/test.lmctl and tidigits to /home/pi/pocketsphinx/test/data/tidigits, this is where pocketsphinx was compiled. Now I get another error, after some time running, I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Segmentation fault has to be debugged with valgrind/gdb

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I added -Q -da -v switchs to g++ command and ran `gdb livedemo.out file.raw`. I get "file.raw" is not a core dump: File format not recognized. May it be that I have an invalid raw file? Or is it something else?

Comment: gdb --args "livedemo.out file.raw"

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I get the following output in gdb: please check edited  question above

Comment: It looks like you also need to edit the paths inside test.lmctl, so it will load the language models from lmctl properly. I also would start with more simple lm than lmctl just to make it running. I doubt you need this lmctl thing.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thanks, it worked. The test.lmctl path I changed was correct, but I should have left tidigts as is. Now it prints correct output. I want to switch to keyphrase catching mode, how can I do this? I now in python you do it with decoder.kws_search, what is the equivalent c function? Thanks for help

Comment: You create a keyword list file and set it with `g_object_set(G_OBJECT(decoder), "kws", "keyword.list", NULL);` instead of lmctl

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thank you so much, everything working now!